# Xor a string that is uint16 or uint32

Tags: java, ios, arrays, swift, xor

I am trying to recreate the following logic I created in JAVA to swift:

```
public String xorMessage(String message, String key) {

    try {
        if (message == null || key == null) return null;

        char[] keys = key.toCharArray();
        char[] mesg = message.toCharArray();

        int ml = mesg.length;
        int kl = keys.length;
        char[] newmsg = new char[ml];

        for (int i = 0; i < ml; i++) {
            newmsg[i] = (char)(mesg[i] ^ keys[i % kl]);
        }//for i

        return new String(newmsg);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
```

I have reached till here while coding in swift3:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


let t = "22-Jun-2017 12:30 pm"
let m = "message"
print(UInt8(t))


let a :[UInt8] = Array(t.utf8)
let v  = m.characters.map{String ($0) }
print(v)
func encodeWithXorByte(key: UInt8 , Input : String) -> String {
    return String(bytes: Input.utf8.map{$0 ^ key}, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? ""

}

var ml :Int = Int( m.characters.count )


var kl :Int = Int (t.characters.count)



var f = [String]()
for i in 0..<ml{

    let key = a[i%kl]
    let input = v[i]


    f.append(String(bytes: input.utf8.map{$0 ^ key} , encoding : String.Encoding.utf8)!)


   // f.append(<#T##newElement: Character##Character#>)
    //m[i] = input.utf8.map{$0 ^ key}

}
```

I am trying to obtain a string(message) which has been xor'ed with a key passed into the above function. But my code in swift is not working as it is returning character array and I want a string, if I try to cast the character array to string it does not show the unicode like \u{0001} etc in the string...

Suppose I get following output :

```
["_", "W", "^", "9", "\u{14}", "\t", "H"]
```

and then I try to convert to string, I get this:

_W^9    H

I want :

_W^9\u{14}\tH

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different problems. First, if your intention is to print
"unprintable" characters in a string `\u{}` escaped then you can use
the `.debugDescription` method. Example:

```
let s = "a\u{04}\u{08}b"
print(s) // ab
print(s.debugDescription) // "a\u{04}\u{08}b"
```

Next, your Swift code converts the string to UTF-8, xor's the bytes
and then converts the result back to a String. That can easily fail
if the xor'ed byte sequence is not valid UTF-8.

The Java code operates on UTF-16 code units, so the equivalent Swift
code would be

```
func xorMessage(message: String, key: String) -> String {
    let keyChars = Array(key.utf16)
    let keyLen = keyChars.count

    let newMsg = message.utf16.enumerated().map { $1 ^ keyChars[$0 % keyLen] }
    return String(utf16CodeUnits: newMsg, count: newMsg.count)
}
```

Example:

```
let t = "22-Jun-2017 12:30 pm"
let m = "message"
let encrypted = xorMessage(message: m, key: t)
print(encrypted.debugDescription) // "_W^9\u{14}\tH"
```

Finally, even that can produce unexpected results unless you restrict
the input (key and message) to ASCII characters. Example:

```
let m = "" 
print(Array(m.utf16).map { String($0, radix: 16)} ) // ["d83d", "de00"]

let t = "a€" 
print(Array(t.utf16).map { String($0, radix: 16)} ) // ["61", "20ac"]

let e = xorMessage(message: m, key: t)
print(Array(e.utf16).map { String($0, radix: 16)} ) // ["fffd", "feac"]

let d = xorMessage(message: e, key: t)
print(Array(d.utf16).map { String($0, radix: 16)} ) // ["ff9c", "fffd"]

print(d) // ﾜ�
print(d == m) // false
```

The problem is that the xor'ing produces an invalid UTF-16 sequence
(an unbalanced surrogate pair), which is then replaced by the 
"replacement character" U+FFFD.

I don't know how Java handles this, but Swift strings cannot invalid
Unicode scalar values, so the only solution would be to represent
the result as an `[UInt16]` array instead of a `String`.